# Uncaught TypeError: auth.get is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to put a Map object created with Immutable into localstorage and then retrieve it later. I am testing that and for some reason I get the error in the title. Here is where I am updating local storage and retrieving.

```js
        this.props.dispatch(saveAuth(defaultAuth))
        localStorage.setItem('auth', defaultAuth);

        const auth = localStorage.getItem('auth');

        console.log(auth.get('token'));
```

If I console.log(auth) it returns the object like so: 
Map { "userType": "admin", "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOjEsImlhdCI6MTUwNzI2MjczMH0.hqnqtjZmX8tPuuJ7bkv3DgQmNpA3-OQhlZoQuFI3IF8" }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Local storage stores values as strings so this is why you get the error when trying to use the **get** method.

I would suggest that you just store the token string in local storage.

If you need to, then you can create a new Map once you retrieve the value.

If you really need to store the whole Map then this might help you:

http://2ality.com/2015/08/es6-map-json.html

```
function mapToJson(map) {
  return JSON.stringify([...map])
}

function jsonToMap(jsonStr) {
  return new Map(JSON.parse(jsonStr))
}
```